# Restore Structure Only

Tags: oracle, backup, restore

We have a database that is 3TB+ in size, and don't have enough space to restore it.

However, we want to retrieve code (stored procs) from a 15 day old backup.

Is is possible to restore the structure only from an Oracle backup?

Answer (score 2):

The source of stored procedures is stored in the `SYSTEM` tablespace in the `SOURCE$` table.

You need not to restore any user data at all, simply restore the `SYSTEM`, `SYSAUX` and `UNDO` tablespaces and skip the rest. You can then open the database with the other tablespaces offlined, and you can access the stored procedures as usual, or query `DBA_SOURCE` or `SOURCE$` directly.